# How to Automatically Check Resource Creation in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, automation, e-commerce

So I'm building an ecommerce project in Rails that uses dynamic pricing for the items - purchasing something increases the price, and when an item isn't purchased for a certain amount of time the price drops.

I could do this manually at an arbitrary but consistent time, but I would really like to run at least the checking automatically. So far the only automation libraries/tools I've found for Rails have been test related, and because this relates directly to resources in Rails, I wasn't sure it made sense to search for a way to do this in Python.

In my project, the resource is called a `Purchase` and has relationships to the `User` and `Item` objects. What I envision is being able to search through all `Purchase` objects created in the last 24 hours. Doing it the other way round (going through all `Items` and their associated transactions) seems like a runtime nightmare, so I assume that's not even an option.

I'd be happy to post any code that would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have `after_create` callback [ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) where you can increase the price. How to reduce price is more complex question, you need a job to run periodically and check for all Purchases.

How to get all related resources Shannon described quite well.